# Shopware 6 : detail: "\"CustomTest\\Controller\\BackendController\" has no container set, did you forget to define it as a service subscriber?"

Tags: shopware

Trying to add some controller into the Shopware 6 administration but facing a 500 error while investigating into the console.

`BackendController` extending to the `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;`

`file: BackendController.php` has a below-route scope.

```
/**
     * @RouteScope(scopes={"api"})
     * @Route("/api/_action/customtest/test", name="api.action.customtest.testConnection", methods={"GET"})
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Context $context
     *
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function getUserConnectionStatus(Request $request, Context $context): JsonResponse
    {
         
            $response = [
                'success' => true,
                'connected' => false,
                'link' => ''
                )
            ];        

        return new JsonResponse($response);
    }
```

`file: connection-service-estatus.js`

```
getConnectionSettingsStatus() {
        const apiRoute = `/_action/${this.getApiBasePath()}/test`;       
        return this.httpClient.get(
            apiRoute,
            {
                headers: this.getBasicHeaders()
            }
        ).then((response) => {
            return ApiService.handleResponse(response);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you register your controller in `src/Resources/config/services.xml` you have to call the method `setContainer`. See [Shopware documentation](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/add-custom-controller#services-xml-example). For example:

```xml
<service id="YourNamespace\BackendController" public="true">
    <call method="setContainer">
        <argument type="service" id="service_container"/>
    </call>
</service>
```